# Sort function based on 2 properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've read a lot about custom sorts and most seem to make use of the greater or less than operator to determine whether one object or another is returned.

However, my situation is a little different. Here's my array:

```
var myStuff = [{name:"one",direction:"receiving"},{name:"two",direction:"sending"},{name:"one",direction:"sending"},{name:"two",direction:"receiving"}];
```

What I need is to have the array end up lumped together like this (name one and two (receiving) and then one and two (sending)):

```
var myStuff = [{name:"one",direction:"receiving"},{name:"two",direction:"receiving"},{name:"one",direction:"sending"},{name:"two",direction:"sending"}];
```

I've put together this cloogy way of doing this but is there something more elegant? Like a nice, custom JavaScript sort function.

```
            var temp = myStuff.split(",");

            $.each(temp, function(key,value){
                if( value.name == "one" && value.direction == "receiving")
                    myStuff[0] = value;
                if( value.name == "two" && value.direction == "receiving")
                    myStuff[1] = value;
                if( value.name == "one" && value.direction == "sending")
                    myStuff[2] = value;
                if( value.name == "two" && value.direction == "sending")
                    myStuff[3] = value;
            });
```

Comment: that's not a sort, that's a use case for [].map()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're doing `myStuff.split(',')`... that won't work on an array.

You can sort an array by custom function like so:

```
myStuff.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.direction.localeCompare(b.direction)
})
```

This will sort the array in place. See also [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [String.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: Good point about the split() on an Array. That was just pseudo code I was writing as a potential approach.